# Output HTML using underscore and backbone

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

The `template`:

```
<div id="page-directory"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="template-site">
  <% if(featured) { %>
    <span class="featured"></span>
  <% } %>
  <a href="http://google.com"><img class="screenshot" src="content/screenshot.png" /></a>
  <div>
    <h2><a href="<%- url %>"><%- title %></a></h2>
    <p><span>Tags:</span><%- tags %></p>
    <p class="colors"><span>Colors:</span><%- colors %></p>
  </div>
</script>
```

The `model` and `view`:

```
// Define a Site Model.
var Site = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    url: '',
    title: '',
    featured: false,
    tags: '',
    colors: ''
  }
});
// Define a Site View.
var SiteView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "article",
  template: _.template($("#template-site").html()),
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

The `collection` and `collection view`:

```
// Define a Sites Collection.
var Sites = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'sites.php',
  model: Site
});
// Define a Sites View.
var SitesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#page-directory'),
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
    this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
  },
  addOne: function(site) {
    var siteView = new SiteView({model: site});
    this.$el.append(siteView.render().el);
  },
  addAll: function() {
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.addAll();
  }
});
```

and `sites.php` returns:

```
<?php

$sites = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'CGART',
        'url' => 'http://google.com',
        'featured' => true,
        'tags' => '<a href="http://google.com">Tag 1</a>' .
        '<a href="http://google.com">Tag 1</a>' .
        '<a href="http://google.com">Tag 1</a>',
        'colors' => '<a href="http://google.com" style="background-color: #000000;"></a>' .
        '<a href="http://google.com" style="background-color: #ffffff;"></a>',
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'CGART',
        'url' => 'http://google.com',
        'featured' => true,
        'tags' => '<a href="http://google.com">Tag 1</a>' .
        '<a href="http://google.com">Tag 1</a>' .
        '<a href="http://google.com">Tag 1</a>',
        'colors' => '<a href="http://google.com" style="background-color: #000000;"></a>' .
        '<a href="http://google.com" style="background-color: #ffffff;"></a>',
    ),
);

print json_encode($sites);
```

In this case `tags` and `colors` are HTML and my code output them like below:

[image]

What is wrong with my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how `<%=...%>` and `<%-...%>` work in Underscore templates. From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Template functions can both interpolate variables, using `<%= … %>`,
>   [...]
>   If you wish to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use `<%- … %>`

So if you say `<%= v %>`, `v` goes right into the template as-is, if you say `<%- v %>` then `v` will be HTML escaped before going into the template. Consider a simple template like this:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-underscore">
    &lt;%=: <%= html %>
    <br>
    &lt;%-: <%- html %>
</script>
```

and throw some HTML at it:

```
var t = _.template($('#t').html());
$(whatever).html(
    t({ html: '<span>html</span>' })
);
```

Given that input, you'll get this output:

```
&lt;%=: <span>html</span>
&lt;%-: &lt;span&gt;html&lt;/span&gt;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pL92b/

Your `tags` comes from the server with embedded HTML:

```
'tags' => '<a href="http://google.com">Tag 1</a>'
```

but you're escaping that HTML in your template:

```
<p><span>Tags:</span><%- tags %></p>
```

You should be able to switch to simple interpolation:

```
<p><span>Tags:</span><%= tags %></p>
<!-- ------------------^         -->
```

to sort out your display.